# What changed in jQuery 1.9.1 to cause the .data extension method to return null instead of undefined when a selector returns no results?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently the application I work on upgraded from jQuery 1.7.1 to 1.10.2 with Migrate 1.2.1 included.

After upgrading we noticed that jQuery returned different results for the extension method `data` depending on if the selector had any results. The `attr` extension method always returns `undefined` regardless of the selector results.

Using the following HTML document I ran tests with versions 1.7.1, 1.8.3, 1.9.1, and 1.10.2.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

    <div id="results">trying to access .data member off a selector that returns no results</div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var target = $("#results");
            target.append("<div>jQuery " + $.fn.jquery + " => " + $("p").data("blah") + "</div>");
            target.append("<div>jQuery " + $.fn.jquery + " => " + $("p").attr("data-blah") + "</div>");

            target.append("<div>jQuery " + $.fn.jquery + " => " + $("body").data("blah") + "</div>");
            target.append("<div>jQuery " + $.fn.jquery + " => " + $("body").attr("data-blah") + "</div>");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

In 1.7.1 and 1.8.3 all results are `undefined`.
In 1.9.1 and 1.10.2 results for an empty selector with `.data("blah")` switched from `undefined` to `null`.

I've reviewed the 1.9.0 upgrade documents as well as the 1.10.0 release notes and haven't found any indication of these changes. Does anyone know why this is? Was it intentional?

I have included a fiddle to show how the various versions of jQuery have handled this.

http://jsfiddle.net/T5L6Y/6/

Comment: I'm sorry you are correct. I included the wrong version of the fiddle. Updating it now.

Comment: In trying to track this commit down it might help to look at [this file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.x-master/src/data.js) on github for changes between Nov. 13th, 2012 and Jan. 15th 2013 ([source](https://jquery.org/history/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change of behavior was not wanted, it is (or rather: it was) a bug.
The difference comes from these lines:

In jquery-1.8.3.js:1772

```
if (value === undefined) {
    data = this.triggerHandler("getData" + part, [parts[0]]);

    // Try to fetch any internally stored data first
    if (data === undefined && elem) {
        data = jQuery.data(elem, key);
        data = dataAttr(elem, key, data);
    }

    return data === undefined && parts[1] ? 
    this.data(parts[0]) : 
    data;
}
```

When the selector is empty, `data` is returned and at this point `data` is `undefined`.

But in jquery-1.9.1.js:1824

```
if (value === undefined) {
    // Try to fetch any internally stored data first
    return elem ? dataAttr(elem, key, jQuery.data(elem, key)) : null;
}
```

When the selector is empty, `elem` is evaluated to false and `null` is returned.
This was not intended and was actually fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/075763b71a72f5973729c4fc8e0b4d839af6cd95) applied in November. Running the code with jquery-1.11.0 has the original behavior: `undefined` is returned.

Comment: Thank you! Seeing the exact bit of code is really helpful. I was doing a little more research and it appears as though this was a bug, it was fixed, then possibly reverted or never actually fixed (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13785). I see the unit test so I'm confident of the fix.

Comment: True I was also a bit confused with the history. The fix may have inadvertently been lost in some merge and re-done later.